# stack 'a' tag over a 'p' tag

Tags: html, css, z-index

What I am trying to do is to stack an 'a' tag on top of a 'p' tag using the `z-index` property. So my html goes like this

```
<div id="personalText" >
    <a href="#" id="editButton"> edit </a>
    <p id="descText">{{profile.desc}}</p>
</div>
```

and my `CSS` goes like this

```
#editButton
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#descText
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

I believe this should stack the `a` on top of the `p` tag but that is not happening. Can anybody please explain what is that I am doing wrongly?

Comment: Why would you *ever* want to do this? Your `a` tag should be somewhere inside your `p`.

Comment: @Sachin By "on top" of the `<p>` tag do you mean "over" (as in overlapping)? Have you tried using `position: absolute` on the `<a>` and `<p>` and setting `#personalText` to `position: relative`?

Comment: Why I want to do this is because I want to show this link only when someone hovers onto the p tag. It's like you can get an edit option when you hover onto the textbox and I dont want the text to move down to make room for the a tag

Comment: @Sachin That is a perfect use case for the `:hover` pseudo-selector or for JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`position: relative` doesn't detach the element from the layout, so by default the element still takes up the same spot it would otherwise.  `relative` has two purposes: to offset an element *relative* to its "real" position in the layout (which would require setting `top`, `left`, etc), and to serve as a non-`static` value so that child elements with `position: absolute` would position themselves relative to it.

With all that said, what you probably want in order to do what you're trying to do, is to set `position: relative` on the parent, and `position: absolute` on the edit link (at least).  But that'd probably be quite ugly, as the text would likely overlap and be unreadable.

Comment: The problem with `position:absolute` is that it is now showing the edit button at the top left corner and if I want to place it in the top right, then I can't just give `right:0px;` because then the link goes to the right end of the screen. Now I need to give the exact pixel location

Comment: @Sachin: That's why you set `position: relative` on the parent (`#personalText` in this case).  Then when you use `right: 0px`, the link goes to the right end of the *parent element*.

Comment: yes that's why I had set position relative, because then I could make it go to the right corner. And I had even come across this article saying I could do it using `position: relative` http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Overlapping_And_ZIndex

Comment: @Sachin: That article is broken to the point of retardedness.  The only way to put one element on top of another using *only* `position: relative`, is to set `top`, `left`, etc to move the element over top of what you want.  And the element still occupies its original space in the layout (the layout engine just moves the box that represents the element, for rendering and interaction purposes), so you can't accomplish your goal of adding the link without stuff shifting around.

Comment: @cHao: Thanks for the insight, I will keep this thing in mind now

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can put the `<a>` tag on top of the `<p>` tag: http://jsfiddle.net/gSWJB/1/

The example shows one possible use case: putting the link on top of the description, where the link might only be shown when the user hovers over it.

Comment: Added some much-needed emphasis.

Comment: I totally understand that this would look ugly but as I have stated in the comment above my purpose is something else. I will make this text a little opaque and will show it only when somebody hovers onto the text box... and thanks for the emphasis

Comment: In that case, I updated the answer with one possible use case.

Comment: In your case setting `right:5px` is working but when I set that property the `editButton` moves to the extreme right of the screen

Comment: @Sachin The 5px is relative to the parent element, in this case the ``<div>``. If you don't set its width, it will extend to the right of the screen.

Comment: I have set the width even then it is movin gout

Comment: @Sachin hard to help without a jsfiddle to reference

Answer (score 1):

You have to also put

```
  #personalText 
  {
    position:relative; 
  } 

  #editButton
  {
      position:absolute;    /* change  */
      top:0;      /* new  */
      left:0;     /* new  */
      z-index:2;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mihalis Bagos states, you need to push your `#descText` element upwards.

Here's the resulting CSS:

```
#editButton
{
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
#descText
{
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    bottom:25px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

Here's the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DpmJS/) resulting from it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect use for JavaScript:

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
```

jQuery

```
$('#descText').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('a').removeClass('hidden');
}, function() {
    $(this).find('a').addClass('hidden');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/joshsmith/PZMUG/)**

Comment: Or, `#personalText>a { display: none; } #personalText:hover>a { display: block; }`.  No jQuery necessary.

Comment: Although its not directly related to the discussion, but is there any inherent advantage of using css over javascript wherever possible. I generally use the `#div_id:hover` feature but didn't think that it can be used in this case also

Comment: @Sachin The `:hover` pseudo-selector only works on `a` tags in older versions of IE. For other `hover` effects, you would need JavaScript. Where possible, you should try to use CSS simply because you should favor keeping your styles to a single location, and JS is less appropriate for that. But JS can do some awesome things, and jQuery in particular helps make stuff like `hover` effects cross-browser.

Comment: "Older versions of IE" meaning IE6.  Which should be ignored, IMO.  IE7 and later don't mind `:hover` on any visible element, as long as it's in standards mode.  And the advantages are, your effects work even when JS is disabled.